# Does a "Helm of Opposite Alignment" work on demons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, alignment

Reading the description of the [Helm of Opposite Alignment](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Helm_of_Opposite_Alignment), I don't see anything which would prevent it from working on demons.

But somehow I have the strong impression that the evil of a demon is an inherent thing and unchangeable. I would be really surprised if this item *did* work normally on a demon.

What is the truth? Is there a rule I've overlooked which prevents it from working (or makes it *much* more difficult) when placed on a demon's head?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, yes, a helm of opposite alignment can affect Demons.

As far as Demons&Devils go, they're "just" outsiders born on evil-aligned planes who're generally always evil and have the Evil subtype (see below) forced upon them. There is nothing mechanically preventing a demon or devil from having nonevil alignments (though they'd also count as evil on top of their actual alignment for spells that deal with alignment). They're still sentient and intelligent beings whose personalities can be changed (through experiences or force).

> A subtype usually applied only to outsiders native to the evil-aligned
>   Outer Planes. Evil outsiders are also called fiends. **Most creatures
>   that have this subtype also have evil alignments; however, if their
>   alignments change, they still retain the subtype.** Any effect that
>   depends on alignment affects a creature with this subtype as if the
>   creature has an evil alignment, no matter what its alignment actually
>   is. The creature also suffers effects according to its actual
>   alignment. A creature with the evil subtype overcomes damage reduction
>   as if its natural weapons and any weapons it wields were evil-aligned
>   (see Damage Reduction, above).

Considering their circumstances of creation, their experiences during life and their society and their tendency to trade souls as currency or eat them, it's unlikely for them to change alignments unless major plot (or supernatural interference like the helm of opposite alignment) happens.

Comment: A demon which turned lawful good might actually be a very interesting character. Although I think that the conflict between its chaotic evil nature and its now lawful good psychology ("*killing mortals is wrong... but their souls are so tasty!"*) might drive it insane (insaner?) sooner or later.

Comment: @Philipp I think it would be a highly interesting plot about a lawful good cleric trying to work with an alignment changed daemon, while continously tries to avoid her suicide.

Comment: @Phillip Well, it could be a good "suffering from inner demons" (or rather, outer demons) character spending the rest of his life searching for redemption or fighting insanity. There are many good stories with "I want to be good despite my heritage/physical form/instinctive desire for evil" type characters.

Comment: @MorningStar, not a demon, and not quite lawful good (more neutral good), but Erevis Cale is a cleric/thief (and more to avoid spoilers) in service of an evil god fighting him on as much as possible to still do good. Read the Twilight Falling trilogy by Paul S Kemp, it's really good!

Comment: @Philipp Succubi *paladins*, complete with LG alignment, is actually something of a minor trope, plus the relatively-famous Falls-from-Grace in *Planescape: Torment* was an LN succubus.

Comment: http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fc/20050824a There's also a wizards article about it.